# Recent Used or Launched GUI Application (Similar to bash_history)

Tags: launcher, zeitgeist, events

Is there something in Gnome or Ubuntu 18.04 that will show the recent used GUI applications.  For the command line commands there is the Bash History log which I use all the time.

If I can see a list, I can build a launcher to quickly launch a GUI from the recent list... saving lots of time in searching for a recently used application.

My current research is showing `gnome activity journal`, which might have had the feature, but it was discontinued and removed from the repository for Ubuntu 18.04.

I also believe this information is included in the Zeitgeist database, of which I'm researching how to extract it.

Cairo Dock has a recent event's app that has an application tab which shows a few of the applications that was run, but it shows less than one out of five applications that are launched.

Comment: KDE has a "recently used" list in the K (application) menu. Is that what you're after? Other launchers that you can install from the Widgets "get new stuff" dialog have the same feature.

Comment: This I'll try to find the KDE recently used application.  I already spent a lot of exploring of the sort features of the launcher which only shows frequent, which never changes.  Many of the recent used applications are not used as regularly as things like Chrome, Writer, and Email.  Thanks for the tip on KDE.  I search for widgets also.

Comment: It's called "history" IIRC, it's a default tab within the [application menu](https://aozoeky4dglp5sh0-zippykid.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/kde-neon-laptop.jpg).

Comment: Thanks.  I have been trying to find a way to add this K Applications menu to the Ubuntu Gnome menu items.  I might be misunderstanding something about this capability.  It's appears that it isn't a standalone feature (such as the KDE file browser and other applications) that can be added to the current Desktop environment.  I'm thinking that you are suggesting that I change my desktop interface.  That's not something I can readily do to my main computer to have a list of recently used applications.  It's something I might consider in the future if that is the only way.

Comment: I too use Kubuntu 18.04 which offers "Recent Applications" but I agree that it would not be trivial, if it's even possible, to add that to a GNOME-based environment. I don't rely on it much because I've bound my most commonly-used applications to keyboard-shortcuts. For the other applications, typing a few letters into *KRunner* pulls up the application. I think the "Dash" in Ubuntu offers something similar.

Comment: @DKBose My most comonly-used applications are a single click away for me as well.  While I don't like having a log list of applications in the Launch bar, for Ubuntu 18.04 you have to.  It's not my most commonly-used applications that I have a problem with.  On certain days there are commonly used applications for that day or period, then it might be weeks or months before I need to use it again, such as Gnome-Disk, Gparted, or an application that I'm writing for a client.  It's a lot of work to have to make short cuts for everything that you need just for a day or two...

Comment: ...it's also a lot of work to have to move my hands from the mouse and hit keys to find the app.  My hand is already on the mouse.  It would be nice if the apps were a quick one or two mouse clicks away, which is would be with a **Recent Apps** menu.  I would never use Gnome-disk or Gparted enough for it to scoll to the top near Chrome or Gnome-terminal.  Setting up keyboard shortcuts and frequently changing them for a short period can easily become a lot of work.  It's something you can't notice when the OS UI will automatically give you a "Recent-App" choice.

Answer (score 0):

Gnome panel has a feature called Frequent apps. You can enable it in the Show applications menu at the bottom of the dialog. By default, the applications menu shows all applications. When you press Frequent, it will show you only the applications that you frequently use by default.

I know it's not exactly what you wanted, it's not sorted from most recently used application to the least recently used one, if you use some applications regularly but not every day, they will probably appear in the list.

It seems that there's no support for Recently used applications out of the box, but the Frequent applications feature relies on some database that stores application usage. This can be enabled or disabled using the `gsettings` `org.gnome.desktop.privacy remember-app-usage` key. It might be possible to write a gnome plugin that relies on that data and adds another option to show recently used applications.